Converting an HTML to PDF consuming too much memory
I am trying to create a PDF using xhtml2pdf lib, but there is always a memory usage issue. There are around 4,000 pages in this HTML.

What did you try?

for certain compliance reason i need to print 4000 page reports. my application needs to print all the records from the DB, this DB entries can be large. for smaller no of records it works fine. but for large xhtml2pdf conversion fails, due to insufficient memory.

@JaydenJiang, my solution is splitting the generated html, and generating pdf in batches of 100 pages and then merging them. This works well ! but it is tedious for me, as i have to split based on certain condition, and i have around 20+ reports, which each has different formats. Using this strategy, i have rewrite the splitting logic for each of them separately.

I have tried PrinceXML HTML to PDF, this software was able to convert the html to pdf, without memory usage spike ! but this is a paid tool.
